# Quasi-compactness of the Zariski topology on the spectrum of abelian category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, abelian-categories, noncommutative-geometry

I'm trying to understand a sufficient condition for the existence of a quasi-compact base of open sets of Zariski topology on the spectrum of an abelian category from https://sasharosenberg.com/?x-portfolio=noncommutative-local-algebra page 29.

Consider the proposition: *Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with property (Sup) and a generator of finite type. Let $\Omega$ be a family of closed subcategories of the category $\mathcal{A}$ such that the intersection $\mathcal{S}$ of all the subcategories from $\Omega$ is finite.Then $\mathcal{S}$ is the intersection of finite number of categories from $\Omega$.*

Now I understand the proof of this proposition. But  I do not understand how it implies the following proposition: *Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with property (Sup) and a generator of finite type. Then the Zariski topology is quasicompact.*

To be precise, the base of closed sets of the Zariski topology is defined by taking the spectrum over left closed sub-categories of $\mathcal{A}.$ Then how does one identify closed sub-categories in this topology so that one is able to use the first proposition?  Sure, I can look into the spectrum of $\mathcal{A^{op}}$, where a left closed subcategory of $\mathcal{A}$ becomes closed subcategory. But then we may not have $\mathcal{A^{op}}$ with *(Sup)* and a generator of finite type.

Thanks in advance!